# Solution of the Seiberg-Witten equations over $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, spin-geometry

I want to find an explicit solution for Seiberg-Witten equations over $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ with Fubini-Study metric.

The Seiberg-Witten equations are defined by:

\begin{align}
F_{A}^{+}&=q(\psi)=\psi \otimes \psi^{\ast}-\dfrac{|\psi|}{2}\\
D_{A}(\psi) &=0
\end{align}

where $D_A$ is the Dirac operator which over $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is $\sqrt{2}(\partial+\overline{\partial}).$

I know that this solution is trivial because the scalar curvature of  $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is positive.

Comment: As you note, the fact that $\Bbb{CP}^2$ is PSC means that there are nontrivial solutions to the (unperturbed) SW equations. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, i want an explict without user the fact that $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is PSC.

Comment: OK. The computation you want is fairly standard for Kahler surfaces - you can find it in most Seiberg-Witten books. One especially clear book is Salomon's notes [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/witsei.pdf); jump to section 12.2. Just ignore his perturbation $\eta$.

Comment: Actually maybe Moore's book is a better reference for this.